# How to get the metadata of a page(minor version) in Tridion for Context Menu Item?

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I am using SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 version.

- Workflow is enabled in the system.
- Context Menu Button added to the editor, which makes use of Page metadata.
- Event System will update the current page path in the page metadata on SAVE event.

But as workflow is enabled in the system, whenever I copy a page from one SG to another SG and clicking the save button explicitly will trigger the Workflow.

Until the workflow is completed I am unable to get the modified metadata in the Context menu JS code (Event System will update the modified the current page path in metadata).

Suspected reason : **Unable to fetch the metadata for minor version.**

Current code :

```
var itemId = selection.getItem(0);
var item = $models.getItem(itemId);
var contentXml = item.getStaticXmlDocument();
var currentPath = $xml.getInnerText(contentXml, "//*[local-name()='current_path']");
```

Please suggest me how to handle the scenario in Java script. Early response is appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Great question, I need to think about that one. On a side note - it looks like you are part of the Area 51 Tridion Beta - Please consider posting your question there as well - http://tridion.stackexchange.com - This should be the primary site for Tridion questions.

Comment: Did you ever resolve getting the minor version of the page or did you re-architect the solution?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are assuming that the item has been loaded. That is not going to be the case very often.

You should check the isLoaded() method and if it returns false, call the load() method with a callback. Then do your check for processing in the callback, since items are loaded asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the metadata on a different event? E.g. on the Copy or Move event?

See `Tridion.ContentManager.Extensibility.Events.CopyEventArgs` or `MoveEventArgs`.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. But I need the page current path to be updated on creation of page too. So SAVE event is the common for both.

Comment: Wouldn't copy do that? But executed inthe beginning so the data might be available.

Comment: Even then the modified data will be available after workflow activity completion because of major version. I need the data before that.